# When implementing wordpress theme it shows only code

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to implement a theme on my website. I went to Appearance implement the owner theme composer and after I implemented all the pages of the template. When the sites open up I just see the coding and less images.

Comment: Are you seeing other themes with no issues? This sounds like a question for the "owner of the theme". Does the theme need a license key?

Comment: provide  any URL or screenshot

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.